# bootstrap scrollReveal not happening

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to add animation on class navbar. I included following links. But still bootstrap scroll reveal not happening. Here in example I just added word nav (don't want to get code to long) to see if it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&subset=cyrillic">
    <script src="jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  
<!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- font awsome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    enter code here


<script>
    window.sr = scrollReveal();
    sr.reveal('.navbar', {
        duration: 2000,
        origin:'bottom'
    })
  </script>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar"> navi </div>    
        <div class="backgroundPic"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the scrollreveal library and called it in wrong mode:

```
window.sr = scrollReveal();
```

instead of (first letter in uppercase):

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
           ^^^
```

The snippet:

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.navbar', {
    duration: 2000,
    origin:'bottom'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar"> navi </div>
        <div class="backgroundPic"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```